# Siteground Website using Google Workspace Email & Deliverability Issues

Tags: email, dns, google-workspace

I am trying to currently get a client's siteground website I am making for them set up so the email accounts that they made with Google Workspace will still send & receive email.

We were able to point the DNS Records and get the domain transferred appropriately. However, email has been a bit iffy.

I made matching email accounts on the server to correspond with their google workspace ones. I then proceeded to modify MX Records, SPF, & DKIM to match what was instructed in [this tutorial that I am linking here](https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_modify_your_mx_records_for_google_apps_mail__gmail/)

This has had mixed results. Firstly, there were no issues with sending email from these google workspace accounts but a few replies I did to these emails sent me an error (no code or anything).

However, other email accounts I tested deliverability with had absolutely no issues with both sending & receving tests. It doesn't seem consistent.

Keep in mind, at the time of writing this I set these email records up about 2 hours ago. Is it just a propagation issue? Any ideas that you all can think of that I might be missing?

I greatly appreciate anyone & everyone for any input you can provide.

Using the tutorial above, I updated my MX records, SPF & DKIM Records for the client.
The TTL is 36000 I should add.

The expected outcome would be that sending & receiving email would work without any issues into their google workspace account.

The issue is while they can send & receive some emails, it doesn't work for every account I have tested. Some bounce, some do not.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [webmasters.se], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again). See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302903/off-topic-my-email-isnt-spam